# GUI app to Convert PDF files to ODT

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, odt

The PDF utilities from the poppler-utils packages include many tools to deal with PDF files, one of them is `pdftotext`.

`pdftotext` can be used to convert PDF files to ODT.

I want the same result using GUI application not command line. What could I use?!

Comment: Did you try Calibre?

Comment: calibre don't help in converting to ODT

Comment: Since LibreOffice has long been able to open PDF files, I suspect I are looking for some particular functionality. Could you detail what is it?

Comment: LibreOffice open PDF?! How come this?!

Comment: LibreOffice is able to open PDF files, really. It could open while preserving layout and text formatting, but slow to open and text are separated into many pieces. As for the GUI application you are looking for--is it important to preserve the text layout and formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Calibre**, which is a GUI for managing and converting ebooks. Also capable of converting to docx.

Answer (score -1):

Try online tools...

Some of them are:

http://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-odt/

https://online2pdf.com/convert-odt-to-pdf

They also has other conversions available

Regards...